# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installer language conflict

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a server with an English Version of Windows that  is located in Germany, which due to "smart" behaviour of the Microsoft SQL website leads to the following problem:

When I try to download the MS SQL SMS installer from the official website, it automatically downloads the German version of the installer `SSMS-Setup-DEU.exe`.

When I then try to run that file, the following error message is displayed:

[image: Setup Blocked Screenshot]

Summed up: Setup was blocked because the installer language (German) does not match the OS language (English).

I have tried a number of different ways to get to an English installer, but in the end, all pages link me to either https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017 or its German version, and even if that site is in English, clicking the download link still downloads the German installer, `SSMS-Setup-DEU.exe`.

I am looking for a way to get the English installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now found out a way to get the English installer.

Basically, I copied the download link from the completed download of the German installer from my browser's download manager, which was: https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/8/3/B839AD7D-DDC7-4212-9643-28E148251DC1/SSMS-Setup-DEU.exe

...and then, I replaced the language code with `ENU`, resulting in the following download link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/8/3/B839AD7D-DDC7-4212-9643-28E148251DC1/SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe

I was positively surprised that that worked, and I was able to install MSSQLSMS without any further problems. Thus, I want to share this workaround for people who are experiencing similar issues.